# Git: Recovering from re-written history. Merge conflicts

Tags: git

I know, I know, re-writing history is terrible, but...

I accidentally checked in a large sql file to git that I needed to remove from all of history.

I clearly didn't do the right thing, but I ran something along the lines of:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch dump.sql' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

It succeeded in removing the file, but caused things to be in a weird state:

- I ran the above command on the branch_a
- branch_b was untouched, and I
- tried to merge branch_a into branch_b
- I got a ton of conflicts, more than it felt like I should have gotten. But I fixed them, and
  committed.
- I then made a change in branch_a, then tried to merge that
  back into branch_b, but got all the same conflicts as the first time,
  even thought I had merged them already.

Any idea how to resolve this? Did some dates get changed on commits causing this weird behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you used `--all`?  ("Something along the lines of" suggests maybe not, and the problem would occur if you ran it only on *one* branch...)

Comment: Good catch. Yes, I did, however, I then pulled the remote copy of branch_b b/c I was nervous about what had happened.

Comment: When you say "pulled" do you mean `git pull origin b`, or something else?  (And if so, what branch were you on when you did `git pull` or `git pull origin b`?)

Comment: yes, 'git pull origin b' while i was in the a branch

Answer (score 0):

OK, per comment, I think I can describe the problem properly now.

(This occurs with any kind of history rewrite, but if it's a non-shared repository, or all users of it are willing to update, it's possible to use `git filter-branch` successfully here.)

The starting point for what you need to know is that git *never changes a commit*, not for `git rebase`, not for `git filter-branch`, not even for `git commit --amend`.  What these commands do, in order to make things look changed, is make *new* commits, based on the old ones, but with something(s) changed.

Then, they move the labels around, so that you see the new commits instead of the old ones.

---

Here's a simple example of a repository with two branches and five total commits:

```
    B <- C   <-- br1
  /
A
  \
    D <- E   <-- br2
```

Commit `A` is the initial (root) commit and then there are two branch structures, consisting of commits `B` and `C` (labeled `br1`) and `D` and `E` (labeled `br2`).  (Each letter here represents some big hairy SHA-1 that is the "true name" of the commit, e.g., `A` might actually be `004257f...`.)

Each commit points back at its ancestor(s), so `C` points back at `B`, and `B` at `A`.  There are no "forward pointers": `A` does not point to either `B` *or* `D`.  The fact that `B` and `D` are both descendents of `A` must be *computed*, by starting at the end-points and working backwards.  (This is how commit `D` can be added without changing `A`.)

Next, you need to know that the word "branch" has two different meanings in git: there's what I call the "structural branches", where you can see that `A <- B <- C  <-- br1` is one branch and `A <- B <- C  <-- br2` is the other branch.  (The two branches share a common point at `A`, so you could say that `br1` consists of just `C` and `B`, and `br2` consists of just `E` and `D`.  But then which branch is `A` "on"?  It's really "on" *both*, in a sense, and if there were any commits before `A` they would also be "on both".  It's sometimes clearer to talk about branches "containing" commits, and there's a `git branch --contains` to show you the labels for branches that contain a given commit.)

Git's labels—things like branch and tag names, although "remote branches" are just labels as well, as are things like the `stash` reference for `git stash`, and so on—get things started: the labels are all find-able by name, and each one gives the raw SHA-1 for a commit<sup>1</sup>.  So `br1` has the raw SHA-1 for commit `C`.  From there, git finds `B` and then `A` as well.  The branch label `br2` finds `E`, which leads to `D`, and then to `A`.

The branch labels are also called "branch", although technically they only identify the *tip* of the branch.  That is, `br1` makes `C` the "end" of a branch.

(Note that if we add a label pointing to `B`—say, add `master`—we've just added another branch.  This applies in both senses: there's a new branch *label*, `master`, and a new "structural branch", containing commits `B` and `A`.  It does not matter that this is overlapped by `br1`; it makes `B` a branch-tip-commit.  Or, we could make `master` point to `C`, so that branches `br1` and `master` overlap exactly.  If we then add a commit `F` to `br1`, the branch-tip `br1` moves forward to point to `F` but the branch-tip `master` remains behind, pointing to `C`.  This automatic advancement of the branch-tip is what it means to "be on a branch".  You can only be on one branch label, even if many labels all point to one commit, and then that's the branch label that advances.)

Now let's look at a simple case of a "history rewrite", where we get onto branch `br2` and do `git rebase br1`.  The idea here is to pick up the parts of `br2` that are not currently shared with `br1`—that would be commits `D` and `E`—and "move" them, resulting in:

```
    B - C           <-- br1
  /       \
A           D - E   <-- br2
```

(I've removed the arrow-heads from the internal commit links here only because they're hard to draw.)  But this is an in-accurate picture.  Git does not actually *move* the commits; this would require changing `D`.  The original commit `D` records its parent commit (or commits but here there's just one), and that's `A`.  Git can't change `D`—but it can *copy* it to a new commit, `D'`, with everything the same except that `D'` says "my parent is `C`":

```
    B - C           <-- br1
  /       \
A           D'
  \
    D - E
```

Once that's in place, git can copy `E` to `E'`, with everything about `E'` the same except (again) its parent: `E'`'s parent is `D'`:

```
    B - C           <-- br1
  /       \
A           D' - E'
  \
    D - E
```

All git needs to do now is move the label `br2`.  The label used to point to `E`; if it now points to `E'` instead, and *nothing* points to `E`, commits `D` and `E` become "abandoned" and can be garbage-collected later:

```
    B - C           <-- br1
  /       \
A           D' - E' <-- br2
  \
    D - E           [abandoned]
```

---

So, `git filter-branch` is basically "git rebase on steriods" as it were.  Instead of copying just a *few* commits, it copies *all* the commits, applying your supplied filters just before making each new commit.  Given our original simple `A`-through-`E`, if you do a `git filter-branch --all`, it copies every commit.

*If* your filters make no changes, the new copied commits are all completely identical (each file is the same, each tree is the same, and each commit is the same, so they all wind up using the same original SHA-1 IDs and none of the labels move either).  But in fact your filter must have made some change, probably fairly far back in history.  Let's assume in this case that it changes what is to go into commit `A`, so that git has to make a copy instead, `A'`.  The result of the filter-branch is this:

```
    B - C   <-- refs/original/heads/br1
  /
A
  \
    D - E   <-- refs/original/heads/br2

    B'- C'  <-- br1
  /
A'
  \
    D'- E'  <-- br2
```

(rather than just abandoning the previous branches, filter-branch leaves labels spelled `refs/original/...`, which you can delete if the result is what you wanted).

Note that it's copied everything from the point-of-change(s) forward.  But it's only done this in *your local repository*.  You mentioned that you had a "remote copy" (presumably something like `origin`).  *They* have only the originals, none of the copies.

Let's draw a more realistic commit graph, with `o` nodes for uninteresting points and a more complex history.  Let's assume further that the `dump.sql` file to be removed occurred before branches `branch_a` and `branch_b` split:

```
--o--W--X--Y--o--o--A   <-- branch_a
            \
             o--o--B    <-- branch_b
```

Here `X` is the first commit containing the unwanted file.  (We'll see why I labeled `W`and `Y` soon.)  The filter-branch command therefore has to copy it, to `X'`, and also all subsequent commits, including the two branch-tips `A` and `B`:

```
--o--W--X--Y--o--o--A    <-- [some label(s), incl refs/original/...]
      \     \
       \     o--o--B     <-- [some label(s)]
        \
         X'-Y'-o'-o'-A'  <-- branch_a
             \
              o'-o'-B'   <-- branch_b
```

Now, you said you "pulled the remote copy of `branch_b`".  That is, you did `git checkout branch_a; git pull origin branch_b`.

Here's where it gets a bit complicated. :-)

`git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  The `git fetch` step goes to the named remote and brings over any new commits.  There were likely no new commits—you already have all the old ones, from which you made copies—but the *merge* step goes wrong here.

To account for this fetch, and/or an earlier fetch, where it says "some labels" above, let's add `origin/` labels too.  There's an `origin/branch_a` pointing to commit `A`, and `origin/branch_b` pointing to `B`.  Again, these are the *old* commits.

So, `git merge` finds the merge-base for commits `A'` and `B`.  That's the point where their history forked, which is the commit just before `X`, i.e., commit `W`.  It then does a merge of `A'` against merge-base `W` and "their" branch `B`, by seeing what changed between `W` and `B`, and what changed between `W` and `A'`.

Whatever else it does, this will bring back the unwanted `dump.sql`, because that was added in going from `W` to `B`, and not added in going from `W` to `A'`.  It also picks up the two commits below where I'll replace `o` with `*`.  So the merged tree at this point has the new `dump.sql` in it, and you get a merge-commit tying `branch_a` to `origin/branch_b`:

```
--o--W--X--Y--o--o--A     <-- origin/branch_a
      \     \
       \     *--*--B      <-- origin/branch_b
        \           `--.
         X'-Y'-o'-o'-A'-M <-- branch_a
             \
              *'-*'-B'    <-- branch_b
```

Now let's say you ask to merge `branch_a` into `branch_b` at this point:

```
git checkout branch_b; git merge branch_a
```

Git again needs to find a merge-base.  (Or, if there are criss-cross merges between `branch_a` and `branch_b`, using the recursive strategy, it has to create a "virtual merge base" by combining equally-good ancestors, but let's keep it simple.)  In this case, the merge-base is `Y'`.  We'll take the changes since `Y'` from `branch_b`, i.e., the copies of the `*` commits, plus `B'`.  But we already have those changes because we merged `origin/branch_b`, which has the same changes (plus `dump.sql`).

Often this will "just work", but presumably in your case things were more complex and you got a bunch of conflicts.

In any case, things are going wrong because you're resurrecting the "old" (pre-"rewrite") branches by using the ones on `origin`.

This sort of thing is why it's difficult to "rewrite history" successfully: you can rewrite your *own* quite easily, but if you have published it elsewhere (e.g., on `origin`), other people have the earlier history, and you can't force them to get rid of it.  You have to get them to voluntarily give up the old "wrong" history and switch to the new "right" history.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or another git object, like an annotated tag; or a label can be an indirect reference, i.e., contain the name of another label.  Usually only the special `HEAD` label is an indirect reference, containing the name of the branch you're on.